# SQL - adding result page numbers based on number of results?

Tags: php, sql, pagination

I have a SQL query that separates the results into groups of 25:

```
$page = 0; // 1, 2, 3
$perPage = 25;

....

ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT " . ( $page * $perPage ) . ", " . $perPage);
```

I'm trying to figure out how I write something that loops through the number of $page returned and then echos a number back to the screen.  Ie.  Page 1, Page2, Page3 - based on $page.

Comment: It's generally referred to as "pagination", and there are numerous questions for how to do it -- see the updated tags for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume the search PHP page is driven throught GET parameters like `page` like `a.php?page=5` or something.

In that case, try something of this sort:

```
$total = //total no. of rows. if using mysql use: mysql_numrows($resource);
$total = ceil($total/$perPage);
for ($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
    echo '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=' . $i . '">Page ' . ($i+1) . '</a>';
}
```

This is just to give you a kick start. You can obviously, take this ahead in the way you would like.

What you are doing is called **Pagination**. Just google for `PHP Pagination`, and you will end up with lots of results. And most of them are just too easy to use.

Try Zend Paginator: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.html